# callback_column not working for connected table in grocery crud

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

I am trying to change column value using `callback_column` function.

```
$crud = new grocery_CRUD();
$crud -> set_table('booking');
//$crud->set_relation('room_id','rooms','name');
$crud->callback_column('room_id',array($this,'_visitor_details_popup'));
```

This code workings well (`_visitor_details_popup` function return value to `room_id`)

```
$crud = new grocery_CRUD();
$crud -> set_table('booking');
$crud->set_relation('room_id','rooms','name');
$crud->callback_column('room_id',array($this,'_visitor_details_popup'));
```

This code NOT workings well (`room_id` not changing)

```
public function _visitor_details_popup($value, $row)
{

    $visitor_details=explode(',',$value);
    return '<a href="#">Name'.$visitor_details[1].'<a>'.'<div class="popup_content">Address'.$visitor_details[2].'Email'.$visitor_details[3].'</div>;
}
```

**Is this a bug in grocery crud?? Any tricky way to solve it??**

Comment: what is on your `_visitor_details_popup`? what do you mean room_id is not changing?

Comment: _visitor_details_popup is the call back function. http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/callback_column

Comment: yes i know it is the callback function what i mean is it is relevant and you need to post it

Comment: Updated..:).. i am trying to make a popup for the column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got a trick. create a function and call it on callback_column parameter..

```
$crud = new grocery_CRUD();
$crud -> set_table('booking');
$crud->set_relation('room_id','rooms','name');
$crud->callback_column(unique_field_name('room_id'),array($this,'_visitor_details_popup')); verity 

function unique_field_name($field_name) 
{
    return 's'.substr(md5($field_name),0,8); //This s is because is better for a string to begin               with a letter and not with a number
}
```